# Does displaying/printing a null value cause NullPointerException

Tags: java

Does displaying/printing a null value cause `NullPointerException` or does only trying to manipulate it?

If I had an array `A` and an array `B` which was twice the size of `A`. If I copied all the elements from `A` into `B` using

```
Arrays.copyOf(A, 2*A.length)
```

When I print `B` using `Arrays.toString(B)`, it happily prints out even `null` values without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: An array of `int` can't have any nulls, because `null` is not a valid value for an `int`. Do you mean an array of `Integer`s?

Comment: I think so too. He is using Integers. [From the Arrays.copyOf doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)): `Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls`. So everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) : Prints a string. If the argument is *null* then the string "*null*" is printed.

Comment: The docs you want to refer to are [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-), not `PrintStream.print`, since the former is what OP is using, but the upshot is the same.